# mariaDB: store data outside the default data directory(in a new disk)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Mysql has "[general tablespace](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/general-tablespaces.html#general-tablespaces-creating)"which can point to any directory outside default data path. by this we can store data to external disks.
Is there similar option for marian db?
Basically I want to store data to a different disk.

Comment: [MariaDB -> CREATE TABLE -> Table Options](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-table/#table-options) - you may set `DATA DIRECTORY` for separate table if `innodb_file_per_table` is enabled. But tablespace operations not enabled in MariaDB - see [CREATE TABLESPACE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-tablespace/) and [ALTER TABLESPACE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/alter-tablespace/).

Comment: can it be a different path in different disk?

Comment: and do i need to set it table by table?

Comment: *do i need to set it table by table?* That's right. For each separate table. And for each separate index if needed. If there is too many objects you may use dynamic SQL. *can it be a different path in different disk?* I think yes, but have not tested. You may test.